# "Subforms" associated with tree view in VB

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, treeview

I am using VB Express 2008 to demonstrate my ideas for an improved UI for an existing product for my colleagues at work.

The current UI has a certain page with ten tabs, allowing the user to define up to ten "things". The available choices for each of the ten "things" are all the same. On each of the ten tabs, there is a checkbox to enable that definition. Generally, a user will never use more than 5 or 6 unique definitions, the rest will remain disabled.

So far, my prototype has a tree view control with one branch to contain this list of definitions, Add and Delete buttons. My idea is: there is one sub-branch to start with (corresponding to the first tab in the current UI); if the user wants addtional definitions, they click Add and other branches are added to the tree view, up to maximum of ten.

I think I should be able to create a "class" that has a sub-UI (like a sub-form in Access) along with behavior code, that can be instantiated with each press of the Add button; each instantiation's settings can be set independently and is displayed in the main UI form )in a panel or frame) when selected in the tree view. For example, suppose the user Adds to make a total of three definitions: the tree view now has three sub-branches, each of which presents the same sub-UI with settings that can be set specific to the selected sub-branch. I'm sure it's possible but not sure how to do it.

I know a comprehensive "answer" might be complicated and long, but I may just need some quick hints to get underway - don't be shy! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think that what you're looking for is a `User Control`. This link contains more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c316f119%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Hi ho1, this article is very interesting, but would require more effort than I can justify for this purpose. I will us a yellow-sticky proptotype instead.

Comment: @knomdeguerre: I'm not sure why you think it would be a lot of effort. Creating a user control is more or less just doing "Add User Control" in the project menu, then add all other controls as needed for one tab on the User control and finally just have 10 instances of the user control, one per tab. A lot easier and quicker than having to keep track of 10 different instances of every control on the tabs. Though obviously it'll be more effort than if you mean that you'll do it via postit notes instead :)